# Django simple authentication application

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I need for a project a simple backend with the following functionality (all must be done via an API since this will be accessed by another program):

1. User can not do anything if he is not authenticated
2. In order to get authenticated the user knows "DEFAULT USER" credentials

   2.1 The user tries to log in with the "DEFAULT USER" credentials

   2.2 The application creates a new User with random pass and username (or token) and returns it to the user so that he can later use those new credentials to authenticate with the server
3. Authenticated users will only be able to CREATE 1 entry in the DB or update the entry created by them.

I have been trying to do this for the past few days however, all the django tutorials I managed to find for DJANGO-REST-FRAMEWORK did not help me.

Currently this is what I got:

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns
from api import views
from api.serializers import UserSerializer

urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^api-classes/$', views.UserStatisticsList.as_view()),
  url(r'^api/$', views.userStatistics_list),
  url(r'^users/$', views.UserList.as_view()),
]

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from api.models import UserStatistics
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserStatisticsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user.username')

    class Meta:
        model = UserStatistics
        fields = ('id','user', 'last_modified', 'statistics_json',)


    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        Create and return a new `UserStatistics` instance, given the validated data.
        """
        return UserStatistics.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        """
        Update and return an existing `UserStatistics` instance, given the validated data.
        """
        instance.last_modified = validated_data.get('last_modified', instance.last_modified)
        instance.statistics_json = validated_data.get('statistics_json', instance.statistics_json)

        instance.save()
        return instance

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # userStat = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=False, queryset=UserStatistics.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username',)
        # fields = ('id', 'username', 'userStat')
```

views.py:

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from api.models import UserStatistics
from api.serializers import UserStatisticsSerializer, UserSerializer
from rest_framework import permissions

@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def userStatistics_list(request, format=None):
    """
    List all code snippets, or create a new snippet.
    """
    if request.method == 'GET':
        userStat = UserStatistics.objects.all()
        serializer = UserStatisticsSerializer(userStat, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = UserStatisticsSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


from rest_framework import mixins
from rest_framework import generics

class UserStatisticsList(
                  mixins.ListModelMixin,
                  mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                  generics.GenericAPIView):
    """
    List all UserStatistics, or create a new UserStatistics.
    """
    queryset = UserStatistics.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserStatisticsSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)

    # def get(self, request, format=None):
    #     userStat = UserStatistics.objects.all()
    #     serializer = UserStatisticsSerializer(userStat, many=True)
    #     return Response(serializer.data)

    # def post(self, request, format=None):
    #     serializer = UserStatisticsSerializer(data=request.data)
    #     if serializer.is_valid():
    #         serializer.save()
    #         return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    #     return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

models.py:
from django.db import models
    from jsonfield import JSONField
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User

```
# Create your models here.
class UserStatistics(models.Model):
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    statistics_json = JSONField()

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="creator")

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('last_modified','statistics_json',)
```

I also tried to implement a custom Authenticator which in my understanding is what gets called when an User wants to Authenticate ... :

```
import string
import random
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, check_password, ModelBackend


class SettingsBackend(ModelBackend):
    """
    Authenticate against the settings ADMIN_LOGIN and ADMIN_PASSWORD.

    Use the login name, and a hash of the password. For example:

    ADMIN_LOGIN = 'admin'
    ADMIN_PASSWORD = 'sha1$4e987$afbcf42e21bd417fb71db8c66b321e9fc33051de'
    """

    ANDROID_LOGIN_USERNAME = "android"
    ANDROID_LOGIN_PASSWORD = "android"

    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        login_valid = (ANDROID_LOGIN_USERNAME == username)
        pwd_valid = check_password(password, ANDROID_LOGIN_PASSWORD)
        if login_valid and pwd_valid:
            # try:
            #     user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            # except User.DoesNotExist:
            #     return None
                # Create a new user. Note that we can set password
                # to anything, because it won't be checked; the password
                # from settings.py will.
            user = User(username=random_string_generator(), password=random_string_generator())
            user.save()
            return user
        return None

    def random_string_generator(size=6, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
        return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))

    def has_perm(self, user_obj, perm, obj=None):
        if user_obj.username == settings.ANDROID_LOGIN_USERNAME:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Can someone please point out what to do next ?

Thank you

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you wanna do. what is "DEFAULT USER CREDENTIALS", user can't signup?   And what "Authenticated users will only be able to CREATE 1 entry in the DB or update the entry created by them." means?

Comment: The idea behind this setUp is that in the end an Android application will submit data to the DB behind the django server and the django app will just be something like a security guard. The Android app will submit json strings which need to be stored in the db for later review (i will change the db to mongoDB since there is no relations between the rows). Each Android device can submit data many times but I need only 1 record per device thus I need to authenticate them,but i don't want the user to do it manually so that they don't get the wrong idea that they have a UserProfile in the Android.